# Insert multiple records for same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. In first table I'm holding some unique records

```
ID                  Name 
_________________________
1                   A
2                   B
3                   C
4                   D
```

Now i need for each ID insert additional 4 rows in second table. So the final result for this is this table:

```
ID                  Factor          Text     
______________________________________________
1                   1               SomeText1
1                   1.2             SomeText2
1                   XY              SomeText3
1                   2.8             SomeText4
2                   1               SomeText1
2                   1.2             SomeText2 
2                   XY              SomeText3
2                   2.8             SomeText4
```

Values for Factor and Text fields are static and can contain numbers and chars.

Is it possible to do that with just pure SQL or i need to solve this through my backend code?

Comment: Why aren't there any rows for `ID = 3` or `ID = 4` in the second table?

Comment: This was just an example...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `CROSS APPLY` to a values table:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t2.Factor
FROM Table1 t1
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1), (1.2), (3.4), (2.8)) t2 (Factor)
```

Output from `SELECT * FROM Table2`:

```
ID  Factor
1   1
1   1.2
1   2.8
1   3.4
2   1
2   1.2
2   2.8
2   3.4
3   1
3   1.2
3   2.8
3   3.4
4   1
4   1.2
4   2.8
4   3.4
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7472f/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
-- Create your first table
CREATE TABLE t1 (ID INT, Name char(1))
GO
-- Create your second table
CREATE TABLE t2 (ID INT, Factor DECIMAL(5,2))
GO

INSERT t1 (ID, Name)
VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'), (4, 'D')
GO

INSERT t2 (ID, Factor)
SELECT t1.ID, Factors.a 
FROM (VALUES (1), (1.2), (3.4), (2.8) ) AS Factors(a), t1

SELECT * FROM t2
```

Comment: This works fine. How to add values to additional field. Let's say that this additional field is nvarchar and contains some letter or text which is also static?

Comment: You can extend Table t1 as much as needed as long as you add the same column to t2 as well.   Is effectively does a CROSS JOIN between t1 and the Factors from the VALUES clause - i.e. joins each value of the Factor to each row of the table